# Reset module.exports object in moch unit test file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm new to nodejs and mocha and I have written js program to list out the files in the folder and also a unit test case in mocha and chai framework.

What I'm trying to achieve here is, before every test case I want to reset the object I set into module.export and I want to get the count of files in the folder which is actually in an array "objResult" and "result".

But I'm getting the count added to the previous test case run,

First test case run, then starts with "0" and it count 85 files. 
See below output,

**Second test case run, instead of starting from "0" it starts from "85"**

```
 readDirectory(dirname)
Start - 0
End - 85
    √ should set array objResult with the values
Start - 85
End - 170
    √ should set array result with the values
```

Below is the code,
test.js

```
let assertMocha = require("assert");
let assert = require("chai").assert;
let expect = require("chai").expect;
let readerExport = require("../temp/DocReader")

describe("readDirectory(dirname)", function () {

    let readerExport1;
    beforeEach(function () {
        readerExport1 = null;
        readerExport1 = require("../temp/DocReader")
        readerExport1.readDirectory(readerExport1.directory);
    })

    it("should set array objResult with the values", function () {
        assert.isAbove(readerExport1.objResult.length, 0, "array should contain some value");
    });

    it("should set array result with the values", function () {
        assert.isAbove(readerExport1.result.length, 0, "array should contain some value");
    });
})
```

DocReader.js

```
let fs = require('fs');
let directory = "C:\\temp\\";
let result = [];
let objResult = [];

function ResultObject(filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

function readDirectory(dirname) {
    if(dirname==null || dirname.trim()==""){
        throw new TypeError("Expects directory path as parameter");
    }
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dirname);

    readFiles(files, dirname);
    var newArray = objResult;

    newArray.forEach(function (item) {
        result.push(item.filename + " | " + item.testId + " | " + item.status + " | " + item.duration + " | " + item.name);
    })
}

function readFiles(files, dirname) {
    if(files==null || dirname==null){
        throw new TypeError("Expects array of files and directory as parameter");
    }

    for (let filename of files) {
        try {
            objResult.push(new ResultObject(
                filename));
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(`${err}`);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    readDirectory:readDirectory,
    readFiles:readFiles,
    ResultObject: ResultObject,
    objResult:objResult,
    directory:directory,
    result:result
};
```

I tried with existing variable i.e. "readerExport"
I created new variable also i.e. "let readerExport1"
but output is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node, modules are [cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), meaning subsequent imports will return the same instance - in other words, what you are trying to do won't work.

To force the module to reload each time you can remove the module path from [require.cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_cache) (although this is inefficient).

Alternatively, you could manually set the state of the module i.e.

```
readerExport.result = [];
readerExport.objResult = [];
```

Or better yet, use an existing stub / mocking library like [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/)